# How to get a unread messages counter on the Evolution app icon on Ubuntu Dock?

Tags: 20.04, indicator, evolution, dock

How I can get unread messages counter on the Evolution app icon on Ubuntu Dock? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and its not working.
Previously I used 20.10 and there it worked correct, but I decited to stick to LTS release. How can I make it work on LTS version?